# Make python3 as my default python on Mac for Fish shell

Tags: python, shell, fish

Every time I type `python` into the console it uses Python 2.7. I would like it to use the latest version (I have it installed), Python 3.9. How do I do this using the fish shell (other StackOverFlow talks about for bash)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, look where it is installed :

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

note the line which ends with python3.9 without anything (as m for example) and type

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python
```

where '/usr/local/bin/python3.9' is what you have copied from above.

type in a new session

```
python --version
```

should be ok..